# mySQLcommand case-sensitivity error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon AWS RDS mySql, and have set lower_case_table_names=1 (not that I believe this setting should make a difference in this case).

I'm executing a query looking like this:

```
insert into trades.fills set version=@version, instanceid=@instanceid, ETC
```

and getting an error back:

```
Table 'trades.Fills' doesn't exist
```

note the change of 'f' to 'F'.

trades.fills does exist in the database, trades.Fills does not.

If I do a "SELECT * FROM trades.Fills" I get the doesn't exist error (correct), and it works if I do "SELECT * FROM trades.Fills" (also correct).

any idea why it would change the case of my query, or what is else is causing the problem?

Comment: Can you set lower_case_table_names=1 on Amazon RDS? I have seen posts about that not working (could be old issue).

Comment: I've been able to set the value, but I don't know whether it has the desired effect. Regardless, here I've got the correct case in my query, so it **shouldn't** make any difference

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that my table was originally called Fills (capital F). I had changed the table name to fills, but there were some triggers which still referred to Fills.